# interpreting line in thread dump

Tags: java, multithreading, stack-trace, dump

I am trying to figure out this line in a thread dump

```
"RMI TCP Connection....." daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000106f12000
   nid=0x1e10 runnable [0xfffffffe48dfe000]
```

What is that address after runnable ? Looks like a stack address is it the top of the stack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the source code it's called last_Java_sp, so it's the top of the stack (or the last known top of the stack).

```
// print guess for valid stack memory region (assume 4K pages); helps lock debugging
st->print_cr("[" INTPTR_FORMAT "]", (intptr_t)last_Java_sp() & ~right_n_bits(12));
```